Get Detail transaction info
I encountered an issue and need help. I want a simple Python script that accepts a transaction hash and prints detailed information for transactions on the BSC blockchain. This includes the transferred token name (BNB, USDT, or any other supported token on BSC), amount, value in BNB, value in USDT, transfer date, and other relevant details.
The following code successfully prints details when the transferred token is BNB, but for USDT transfers, it sets both the USD value and BNB value to 0. Any help would be appreciated!


import requests
import json

# Replace with your BscScan API key
api_key = ''
transaction_hash = ''

# URL to get transaction details
url = f'https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash={transaction_hash}&apikey={api_key}'

# Send request to get transaction details
response = requests.get(url)
transaction_data = response.json()

# Extracting necessary data
gas_price_wei = int(transaction_data['result']['gasPrice'], 16)
gas_used = int(transaction_data['result']['gas'], 16)
value_wei = int(transaction_data['result']['value'], 16)
print(transaction_data)
# Convert gas used and gas price to BNB
gas_fee_bnb = gas_used * gas_price_wei / 1e18  # Convert from wei to BNB
value_bnb = value_wei / 1e18  # Convert from wei to BNB

# Fetching the current price of BNB in USD from CoinGecko API
bnb_price_url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=binancecoin&vs_currencies=usd'
bnb_price_response = requests.get(bnb_price_url)
bnb_price_data = bnb_price_response.json()
bnb_price_usd = bnb_price_data['binancecoin']['usd']

# Calculating the gas fee and value in USD
gas_fee_usd = gas_fee_bnb * bnb_price_usd
value_usd = value_bnb * bnb_price_usd

# Prepare the final JSON
transaction_details = {
    "transaction_hash": transaction_data['result']['hash'],
    "block_number": int(transaction_data['result']['blockNumber'], 16),
    "from": transaction_data['result']['from'],
    "to": transaction_data['result']['to'],
    "value_bnb": value_bnb,
    "value_usd": value_usd,
    "gas_price_gwei": gas_price_wei / 1e9,  # Convert from wei to Gwei
    "gas_used": gas_used,
    "gas_fee_bnb": gas_fee_bnb,
    "gas_fee_usd": gas_fee_usd,
    "token_type": token
}

# Print the JSON data
print(json.dumps(transaction_details, indent=4))



and the results look


{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 1, 'result': {'blockHash': '0xa9b8ce9b06967a93563ec47c1a48a984beadd47e2ef1c35b4fcb1c82606d10cf', 'blockNumber': '0x1f2335b', 'from': '0xeb2d2f1b8c558a40207669291fda468e50c8a0bb', 'gas': '0x32918', 'gasPrice': '0x165a0bc00', 'hash': '0x3e459a7306429d3d4910e678fe4e27f119c4db36c6392c643a37e69bd7816d46', 'input': '0x', 'nonce': '0xad7576', 'to': '0x0b2c0240719cafc446d6e506e91a269a6f60b36c', 'transactionIndex': '0x10', 'value': '0x6223fff7e11400', 'type': '0x0', 'chainId': '0x38', 'v': '0x93', 'r': '0xfa69df41a1072e58dfd278ccf4a370af5b73d20a9067c45b2856e3ea78a98dee', 's': '0x57ff6de9e963c99d3f04d6292f19fffda0cbcb37182181752454f32e6c2c3646'}}
{
    "transaction_hash": "0x3e459a7306429d3d4910e678fe4e27f119c4db36c6392c643a37e69bd7816d46",
    "block_number": 32650075,
    "from": "0xeb2d2f1b8c558a40207669291fda468e50c8a0bb",
    "to": "0x0b2c0240719cafc446d6e506e91a269a6f60b36c",
    "value_bnb": 0.02762413,
    "value_usd": 15.05515085,
    "gas_price_gwei": 6.0,
    "gas_used": 207128,
    "gas_fee_bnb": 0.001242768,
    "gas_fee_usd": 0.67730856,
    "token_type": "BNB"
}



But if the transfer is USDT, it shows


{
    "transaction_hash": "0x74ba4eff9e1740560ab954f3aac91b6a8d7c3f549c4b27292973ef2ffcc40f88",
    "block_number": 33456122,
    "from": "0xa180fe01b906a1be37be6c534a3300785b20d947",
    "to": "0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955",
    "value_bnb": 0.0,
    "value_usd": 0.0,
    "gas_price_gwei": 6.0,
    "gas_used": 207128,
    "gas_fee_bnb": 0.001242768,
    "gas_fee_usd": 0.67730856,
    "token_type": "BNB"
}




You get the value in USD, only for the transaction of bnb tokens, since this is the token of the network itself, to get information about tokens that work on a smart contract, you must write a script to work with the bsc node. You will need to do this web3.py . Then, through third-party APIs, get the price of the token
here is an example code that gets the address of the receiver and sender, as well as the value. You should take into account that the value is written there, without taking into account decimal
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org"))

tx = w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt("{tx_hash}")

print(tx)
tx_logs = tx.get('logs', {})[0]
_, addr_from, addr_to = tx_logs.get("topics")
value = tx_logs.get("data")

print(f"{hex(int(addr_from.hex(), 16))} -> {hex(int(addr_to.hex(), 16))} -- {int(value.hex(), 16)}")

